# Telerik Kendo UI Grid Customizing Excel Export

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2 that may have a lot of data. As a result, I am using an API call that includes a count and putting the data in a paginated grid. When I click on the Export to Excel button, it only returns the data that is shown. I would like to be able to export the entire dataset instead.

I think I am supposed to be using the fetchData method and have included it in the grid as follows:

```
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="MyExport.xlsx" [fetchData]="allResults"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

However, the allResults method must return an ExcelExportData object. My method call to the API returns an observable that is then parsed. I have tried returning the data in the subscribe event, but it gives me a TypeScript error that the method must return a value. If I change the return type to "any", it fails on my call to "this" when getting the filters applied externally.

This is my current fetch method:

```
allResults(): ExcelExportData {
    if (!this.sort.length) {
        this.sort.push({ field: undefined, dir: undefined });
    }

    this.myService.resultsGet(
        this.filters.date,
        ...
        undefined,  // skip
        undefined,  // take
        this.sort[0].field,
        this.sort[0].dir
    ).subscribe(
        (pagedList: any) => {
            for (let item of pagedList.results) {
                // manipulate a few things here
            }
            return { data: pagedList.results };
        },
        e => { console.log(`error: ${e}`); }
    );
}
```

Is there any way to set this up to make an external API call using angular component filters and returning the data through a subscribe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two things going on:

- ***this* undefined**:  fetchData is not called in the context of your component instance, so you need to bind it yourself

  ```
  this.allResults = this.allResults.bind(this);
  ```
- **return value**: assuming your service is fetching from a server, you need to return a promise or an observable to fetchData, so you don't want *subscribe()*, you want *map()*

Putting it all together, you get something like this:

```
   constructor(
     public myService: MyService
   ) {
     this.allResults = this.allResults.bind(this);
   }

   allResults() {
     if (!this.sort.length) {
      this.sort.push({ field: undefined, dir: undefined });
     }

      this.myService.resultsGet(
        this.filters.date,
        ...
        0,  // skip
        undefined,  // take
        this.sort[0].field,
        this.sort[0].dir
      ).map(response => {
        // manipulate a few things here
        return <GridDataResult> {
          data: response.value,
          total: response.count
      }
    }
```

Update:  Here is a plunker that shows  this, based off of one of Telerik's examples.

[excel export plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZLtzP6GNYi2DIU7g8qt?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this undefined! The return is still an issue. The problem I am having is that the grid only has a subset of the data required in the export. I already had the code you wrote for allResults for the method I use to load the grid (although I use a subscribe instead of a map). That works fine because the grid can handle Observables. When I click the "Export to Excel" button, I need a different set of parameters for myService.resultsGet method that returns an ExcelExportData type (allResults():ExcelExportData). Putting the return in the map returns a void. Can Kendo do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I added a plunker above that shows getting all the data and modifying it.